# Vue complains about undefined properties that are in fact defined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a weird occurrence where vue claims a property is undefined on the instance when it really is defined. I have made a minimal version of the component that still displays this weird behaviour. This is my component:

```
    <template>
      <div>
        <h1>{{ formtitle }}</h1>
      </div>
    </template>
    <script>
      export default {
        name: 'RequestPasswordChange',
        data () {
          return {
            formtitle: 'blabla'
          }
        }
      }
    </template>
```

When viewed in the browser, vue throws the familiar error:
Property or method "formtitle" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render, but as can bee seen, the property is defined in the data function. What other conditions could trigger this error?

Comment: You have </template> instead of </script> as the final closing tag, could it be this?

Comment: You're totally right! Actually the wrong end tag was a typo I made while typing in this question, but my original compoment was missing the closing </script> tag.
Thanks, you should have made it an answer, so I could tag it as the correct answer.
It bugs me how I can loose time over such a simple typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `</template>` instead of `</script>` as the final closing tag.

Comment: Just in case anyone thinks this is not a very useful question/answer: I had searched the web for hours before submitting this quention. Had I found anything resembling this, I would have lost 5 minutes, instead of several hours over this. It's useful IMO to know that this error can be triggered by a missing closing script tag.